# Text2Speech not working

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

When I run my app, if I add multiple text to speech requests, they will queue up and play one after the other. If I press the stop button, they stop playing and when I move out of the view controller, and back in to the view controller, when I try to start them again nothing will play. Does anyone know why this is?

Is this because there were text2speech items queued up, and they never got chance to play so the other items are stuck behind them. If so, how do I delete the items queued up when I leave the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

This simple line of code does the job

```
synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
```